# What is a "Rabbi Meir Bal Hanes" tzedaka?

Tags: names, tzedakah-charity, organizations

I have seen several Tzedaka organizations calling themselves something like "[Colel Chabad](http://www.colelchabad.org/) (or Kupas Ha'Ir) Rabbi Meir Baal Haness Charity".

What does it mean that it is a "Rabbi Meir Baal Haness" charity and what does an organization have to do to get such a title?

Comment: That site makes it sounds like the Alter Rebbe was an accountant!

Comment: @isaac, it's not only a chabad thing. I am almost sure there are non-chabad tzedakas going under the "Rabbi Meir" name

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, Fair enough, given your edit.

Answer (score 5):

This is derived from the famous story about the Roman guard being saved after invoking R' Meir's merit ([Avoda Zara 18a,b](http://dafyomi.co.il/azarah/points/az-ps-018.htm)). The [Medrash Talpiyot](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20804&st=&pgnum=21&hilite=) writes that someone who lost something should promise to donate some money for lamp oil for the merit of R' Meir's soul. The [Chida](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40655&st=&pgnum=156) also cites the custom to donate oil or money for the merit of R' Meir's soul when someone is in any sort of distress. He adds that the person would also recite the prayer of the Roman guard: "*Elaka d'Rabbi Meir aneini*." The Chida cites the [Rama miPano](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=45098&st=&pgnum=56&hilite=) that the supplicant's intention should simply be that he accedes to whatever the lofty intentions were behind R' Meir's own prayer to the Almighty.

Beginning [over two hundred years ago](http://www.kramban.org/lista.htm), charitable organizations, particularly those benefiting the poor and scholars in the Land of Israel, began to spring up under the name of "Rabbi Meir Ba'al Haness." This includes a well known [Jerusalem charity founded in 1860](http://www.rabbimeirbaalhaneis.com/Rabbi%20Yosef%20Zundel%20Salant.asp) by R' Shmuel Salant. Since then, it has become popular to start charitable organizations under that name. These organizations typically cite the Talmud's story about R' Meir and assure people that they will be saved from trouble or find lost objects if they donate to that organization, possibly with the additional requirement of reciting a formula including the Roman guard's prayer and a Midrashic teaching (B'reishis Rabba, 53:14) about finding hidden things (e.g., see [here](http://chibasjerusalem.com/id23.htm)).

In reality, an organization that decides to name itself something like "Rabbi Meir Baal Haness" does not automatically acquire a superior claim to the *segula* described in the first paragraph.

Comment: Fred, thanks for this answer! Do you have a source you can cite for your points about history and the contemporary charity scene?

Comment: Both these links say that the segula is to give charity to the poor in eretz yisroel in his merit. Any organization that does that is a R' Meir Bal Haness organization. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabbi_Meir#Legend and http://www.rabbimeirbaalhaneis.com/history_rmbh.asp

Comment: @Menachem, can you find a reliable source for this that is not Wikipedia or one of the charities themselves (preferably dating back more than 200 years)? Everyone has heard of this, but perhaps it is only because these tzedakas keep saying this. (I'm referring to the claim in your first sentence).

Comment: @Menachem, for example, does [this organization](http://www.guidestar.org/organizations/02-0712007/rabbi-meir-baal-haness-dchasidei-umosdos-lelov-kol.aspx#mission) (apparently run by Chassidei Lelov?) collect for Eretz Yisrael?

Comment: @Fred: I have no knowledge of that organization.

Comment: In Keter Shem Tov HaShalem it is quoted in the name of the Baal Shem Tov that pledging to a Beit HaKnesset in the name of R' Meir can miraculously save someone. - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=16081&hilite=93af50e4-e6da-4101-9e18-92dc242ed89d&st=%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%94%d7%90+%d7%93%d7%9e%d7%90%d7%99%d7%a8&pgnum=271 - not just in Israel.

Comment: @Menachem, that last comment of yours sounds like the makings of an answer.

Comment: I didn't read the whole thing, but the S'dei Chemed references a Teshuvah of the Chatam Sofer, discussing if one just pledged to R' Meir Baal Haness without specifying poor in Eretz Yisroel, may one give the poor in the city. - http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14150&hilite=48923c93-55b3-4f1e-9298-6e9504cf7250&st=%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%90+%D7%93%D7%9E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%A8

Comment: And here's a Responsa from Rabbi Shlomo Tzvi Shik  http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=389&hilite=5f7419d0-5a8f-4972-afe0-aa02da1c196c&st=%d7%90%d7%9c%d7%94%d7%90+%d7%93%d7%9e%d7%90%d7%99%d7%a8&pgnum=187 who writes: until this day thousands and thousands people live with the belief that they throw a coin into a charity box that is used to support the poor of Eretz Yisroel and they say "The G-d of R' Meir Answer Us"

Comment: @Menachem, indeed. As far as your last comment, R' Shick wrote that way after these tzedakas were established.

Comment: It is a common mistake to refer R.Meir Baal Haness as the Tanna R.Meir. The sefer Seder Hadoros quotes the sefer Gelillos Eretz Yisroel that R. Meir Baal Haness is buried in Gush Chalav, and he doesn't know who he was. R. Meir the Tanna is buried in T'veryah and every knows who he was.

Comment: It should be noted that Midrash Talpiyot is a Sabbatean work.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this website (an internet portal for a self-named Rebbi Meir Ba'al HaNes charity](http://chibasjerusalem.com/id23.htm), FWIW),

> "There is a Minhag (custom) to give Tzedakah (Charity) to the Tzedakah of Rabbi Meyer Baal Haness  when one is in a situation of any need or distress. This custom has its roots in the Talmud. Prior to Rabbi Meyer Baal Haness's passing he observed the terrible situation that resulted from  the hunger in Eretz Yisrael. He proclaimed that he would intercede for whoever would give Tzedakah for his Neshamah, and the money should be distributed to the poor of Eretz Yisrael."

It would seem from there that any charity that distributes funds to the needy of Eretz Yisrael <s>has self-interest in naming</s> should name itself "Rebbi Meir Ba'al HaNes".